# Impossible to access an attribute ("user") on a null variable

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, entity

I am getting this error and cant figure out how to solve it. The idea is to list all books of a user. the path when called with the ID of the user works fine for example : userbooks/4 . but called the with the username userbooks/paul i get this error "Impossible to access an attribute ("user") on a null variable."

```
   <h2 > <a href="{{ path('userbooks',{'user' : entry.user}) }} ">{{ entry.title | title }}</a></h2>
```

viewuserbookAction:

```
  public function viewuserbooksAction($user)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $book = $em->getRepository('BookReviewBookBundle:Book')->find($user);

    return $this->render('@BookReviewBook/Book/viewuserbooks.html.twig',
        ['book' => $book]);

}
```

viewuserbook.html.twig

```
{% extends '@BookReviewBook/layout.html.twig' %}
{% block title %}{% endblock %}
{% block body %}

  {% for book in book.user.entries %}
  <h1>{{ book.title }} </h1>
<div>
<img class="img-valign" src="{{ asset('images/book/'~ book.path )  }}" , style 
 = "width:300px;height:300px;" class="img-thumbnail " />
<span class="text2">{{ book.author }}</span>

{{ book.averageRating |rating }}
</div>
<hr class="style4">
<p>{{ book.summary|nl2br }} </p>
<p><small>Posted by {{ book.user }} on {{ book.timestamp|date('H:i d/m/y') }}
</small>
 </p>
<hr class="style4">

{% endfor %}
```

routing.yml

```
 userbooks:
     path: /userbooks/{user}
     defaults: { _controller: BookReviewBookBundle:User:viewuserbooks }

  view:
     path: /view/{id}
     defaults: { _controller: BookReviewBookBundle:Book:view }
     requirements:
       id: \d+
```

Comment: That's probably because your Book Entity has a connection to User via ID and not via username.

Comment: There's a lot of  `user` variables in your code snippet. Where is exactly the one causing this error?

Comment: @DonCallisto this path {{ path('userbooks',{'user' : entry.user}) }} is pointing to the username variable. It is possible to change it to point at the user ID instead?

Comment: Yes just put `entry.id` instead of `entry.user`

Comment: What entry is? You don't have any entry variable. Just pass it in render controller's method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the reply and help. Works perfectly now. had to find by username

viewuserbookAction:

```
public function viewuserbooksAction($username)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $book = $em->getRepository('UserBundle:User')->find($username);

    return $this->render('@BookReviewBook/Book/viewuserbooks.html.twig',
        ['user' => $book]);

}
```

viewuserbook.html.twig

```
 {% extends '@BookReviewBook/layout.html.twig' %}
 {% block title %}{% endblock %}


 {% block body %}


 {% for book in user.entries %}
 <h1>{{ book.title }} </h1>
 <div>
 <img class="img-valign" src="{{ asset('images/book/'~ book.path )  }}" , 
   style 
   = "width:300px;height:300px;" class="img-thumbnail " />
 <span class="text2">{{ book.author }}</span>

  {{ book.averageRating |rating }}
  </div>
  <hr class="style4">
   <p>{{ book.summary|nl2br }} </p>
    <p><small>Posted by {{ book.user }} on {{ book.timestamp|date('H:i d/m/y') 
   }}
   </small>
   </p>

  {% endfor %}

  {% endblock %}
```

routing.yml

```
userbooks:
     path: /userbooks/{username}
     defaults: { _controller: BookReviewBookBundle:User:viewuserbooks }
```

index.html.twig

```
  <h2 > <a href="{{ path('userbooks',{ username : entry.user.id}) }} ">{{ 
  entry.title | title }}</a></h2>
```